# JPA issue on Websphere -- works fine on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, jpa, websphere, openjpa

I have a Spring 3 application using openJPA as persistence management, following section works fine in STS/Tomcat

```
@Transactional
createBalance(){
.....
    Balance balance = new SummaryBalance();
    balance.setName(name);
    balance.setCurrency(currency);
    balance.setClosingTimestamp(closingTime);
    balance.setStatus(BalanceStatus.OPEN);
    balance.persist(); // persist !!
 ......

    balance.setCloseAmount(amount);
    balance.setLastUpdateTimestamp(now);
}
```

However, when deploying same code in websphere 7, the `closeAmount` and `lastUpdate` does not update(both fields in DB didn't get update but from log both field can return values by their getter) then show up as null, but changes to other fields before `persist()` do take effect when the method finished. So I bet when the method finishing WS didn't flush the changes towards these fields.

I thought the JPA(regardless of vendor) should keep the balance entity object managed after `persist()` and flush the object after the method is finished with later changes. Turns out Websphere 7 doesn't make it. Even I put a `merge()` method

```
    balance.setCloseAmount(amount);
    balance.setLastUpdateTimestamp(now);
    balance.merge();
```

still does not help.

Questions:

1. OpenJPA has already been included as dependencies in the deployment, but why still websphere need to involve with the JPA management?
2. How to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you use OpenJPA and the EE containers' implementation classes instead of a library like Hibernate that removes any dependancy on an EE container?

Comment: @Brad I will mark your word on the next project. This one is a legacy project so there is not much we can do on that level. But webshpere is well-compatible with OpenJPA right?

Comment: I don't know. I develop on Websphere and my applications use Hibernate. My question was one of genuine curiosity as I had not considired using OpenJPA before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this exactly answers your question, but I think you should do some reconfiguration to use WebSphere capabilities, please check [Spring 3.1 documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-application-server-integration-websphere)

> 11.8.1 IBM WebSphere
>
> On WebSphere 6.1.0.9 and above, the recommended Spring JTA transaction
>   manager to use is WebSphereUowTransactionManager. This special adapter
>   leverages IBM's UOWManager API, which is available in WebSphere
>   Application Server 6.0.2.19 and later and 6.1.0.9 and later. With this
>   adapter, Spring-driven transaction suspension (suspend/resume as
>   initiated by PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW) is officially supported by IBM!

and

> 11.9.1 Use of the wrong transaction manager for a specific DataSource
>
> Use the correct PlatformTransactionManager implementation based on
>   your choice of transactional technologies and requirements. Used
>   properly, the Spring Framework merely provides a straightforward and
>   portable abstraction. If you are using global transactions, you must
>   use the org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager
>   class (or an application server-specific subclass of it) for all your
>   transactional operations. Otherwise the transaction infrastructure
>   attempts to perform local transactions on resources such as container
>   DataSource instances. Such local transactions do not make sense, and a
>   good application server treats them as errors.

Comment: Thanks Boris but are we talking about JTA or JPA? I think my situation only involve with one data source so there is no JTA transaction manager within the application.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out a solution myself with guess work. Simply just place the persist() by the end of the whole method body.

```
@Transactional
createBalance(){
.....
    Balance balance = new SummaryBalance();
    balance.setName(name);
    balance.setCurrency(currency);
    balance.setClosingTimestamp(closingTime);
    balance.setStatus(BalanceStatus.OPEN);
 ......

    balance.setCloseAmount(amount);
    balance.setLastUpdateTimestamp(now);
 ......
    balance.persist(); // persist !!
}
```

That can make sure every fields are set before the method finished.
Both merge() and explicit flush() won't do the job but only with above compromise. Still not quite sure about the official work around....

I will keep this thread open for any new thinking come in :)